# In Spring4D is it not possible to register a TPair<String,String>?

Tags: delphi, spring4d

The following code gives the error 'Incomplete registration for type: TPair<System.string,System.string>' but for the life of me I can't figure out what is missing.
I even tried registering String.

```
var Container:=TContainer.Create;
try
  Container.RegisterType<TPair<String,String>>().InjectConstructor(['A','B']);
  Container.Build;
  var A:=Container.Resolve<TPair<String,String>>;
  OutputDebugString(PChar(A.Key));
finally
  Container.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Think I have found it.  I think it is because TPair<> is a record and not a class.

Comment: That's what the code that raises the error says: `if model.ComponentType.TypeKind = tkClass then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
Container.RegisterInstance(TPair<string,string>.Create('A', 'B'));
```

That will let the container know about `TPair<string,string>` which has those given `Key` and `Value`.

Comment: I dumbed it down for the example but I was really trying to resolve a named list of factories so it would be more like TPair<String,IMyFactory>().InjectConstructor(['Type1Name','MyFactoryForType1']);

Comment: Then you should modify your question - one can only answer what has been asked and not what actually was meant by the questioner. Also, you do realize that a `TPair<String,IMyFactory>` cannot be filled with two strings, yes?